# Angular date property of client object does not match what is received on server

Tags: .net, angular, webapi

I am currently putting an Angular 14 front end on a much older application, which uses a .Net Web API on the back end.
The application presents a list of shifts, which are a collection of a larger object.
When data is pulled from the server, the time is correctly bound and presented - the values below match what is in the database:

[image]

I am not changing any thing at all right now, but am just trying to save the exact same information back to the server. Here is what my JSON object looks like when I inspect it in Chrome's debugging tool, just before it is sent to the server:

[image]

As you can see, the start and end times are correct, matching what is in the database (I am only concerned with the time portion, not the date). However when I receive that model on the server, the times have changed. The start time is now 6:50 PM instead of 1:00 PM, and the end time is now 2:50 PM instead of 9:00 PM.
Screenshot:

[image]

I understand that the date object received on the server is in UTC time.
And if I call the .Net Date method "ToLocalTime()" on the start time I do get a local time of 12:50 PM, which is *close* to 1:00 PM. And I get similar results for the end  time.

But I cannot for the life of me understand how I can be losing 10 minutes.
Can anyone explain this?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Per request, here is a screenshot of what is being submitted after the year is changed (which preserves the correct time):

[image]

Comment: can you please updated your questions with a snippet of the request payload sent to the server?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the missing 10 minutes was caused by the year being 1753. I don't pretend to understand why that would make any difference, but when I changed startDate and endDate by calling .setFullYear(2022), the 10 minute issue was resolved.